# Making a PUT request in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This was my first crack at making a PUT request, after making a successful GET I was excited then following a tutorial I get an error that I don't quite understand.

Here is the error

`"{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined property: Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ParameterBag::$name","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\basketball-app-framework\\app\\controllers\\PlayersController.php","line":67}}"`

I get that its on line `67` and the property is obviously undefined, but I followed the tutorial and I am not sure how else to write this, or why it's not working like the tutorial. I feel it could be because of mod_rewrite, I had an issue with that, and had to set some things in the apache config file just to make the GET request, so possibly I need to change some things to make the PUT.

Here is the code to PUT data.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::json();
    $player = Player::find($id);
    $player->name = $input->name; // this is line 67
    $player->save();
}
```

again the error occours with `$player->name = $input->name;`

In my show method when I send a GET

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Player::find($id);
}
```

`Player::find($id);` obviously works

so the `$player` variable inside my update shouldnt be causing an issue in accessing the `name` attribute, so I am at a loss and hoping someone can help this noob out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $player = Player::find($id);
    $player->name = $input['name'];
    $player->save();
}
```

**Or Try this:**

```
public function update($id)
{
        $player = Player::find($id);
        $player->name = Input::get('name');
        $player->save();
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks man, it worked I really dont know how I could have figured this out any other way. The `$input['name']` actually makes more sense to me than `$input->name`. I wish I could give you more compliments lol but thanks so much for the help. Have a good one!

Comment: Just to help you little more, I often use this `$player->fill(Input::all())` which helps you to set all properties just in one line :)

Comment: Thanks, all tips at this time are more than valuable, I am trying to get the hang of this new flow. I spent a long time learning backbone.js now I need to get the hang of this. I appreciate it +1